# Visual Studio 2013 started lagging during debuggin ASP .NET MVC 5.1 application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

Till yesterday during debugging I could freely modify views and then reload the website in the browser. But know even when I scroll it freezes completely for even 10 seconds. Sometimes works for few seconds without a lag. When I do not scroll CPU usage by VS2013 is almost 0% when I scroll it goes up to 25 and it freezes constantly.

What happenned and what can I do?

Comment: Are you watching list variables that require a lot of refresh?  I notice that lags my VS quite a bit.

Comment: @Scottie I didn't add any watching list. I don't know even how to add one.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed?  Frequently, bugs in extensions cause this problem... Usually restarting Visual Studio fixes it, but sometimes you need to restart the computer due to resource exhaustion or even paged pool locks.

Answer (score 0):

any anti-virus software sheduled file system checks? How much RAM installed in your computer? VS2013 minimal requirements is 1GB. Also whith OS do you run? It all sounds like you don't have enought. In my practice when usage of RAM is abount 75-80% VS begin freezes. Or if there is heavy CPU loading in background, caused some hidden processes.

Comment: No anti-virus, 8GB RAM, it didn't freeze before(for 3 months of development) started few days ago. Windows 8.1 Pro 64 bit, VS 2013 Ultimate with all updates.

Comment: 8GB are very few. try check in realtime RAM usage. In my situation after installing additional 8gb all lags gone.

Answer (score 0):

I am experiencing the same thing, it happens randomly. I think the problem with mine is that my laptop is extremely old and couldn't handle the process. When it does happen, closing VS and the browser and then reopen them seems to solve the problem.